# Nginx how to run server.js file (not html) always in some port?

Tags: angular, ubuntu, nginx

I am new to nginx and I know how to run simple root /var/www/example.com if it has html, it will run. But what if I have Angular app, and I have to run server.js in order to get ssr working ?

1. I can run it with node server.js , but the server will be busy and I cant write anything then.
2. I tried to change path to my server.js , but it was an error.

How to achieve something similar to this :

1. node server.js - it would run on my selected port always and I could do anything else in the server without stopping node server.js command.

Comment: sounds like you're looking to do a nginx reverse proxy pass to your node's app port?

Comment: Now i installed pm2 and runned it with it, it works well, but i dont really know how to enable ssl and domain when it is running with pm2

Comment: If you followed the answer below, you can configure nginx to get an SSL certificate. If you have an actual domain name pointing to your server, you can look into provisioning a letsencrypt cert - it's quite a painless process!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your intention is to deploy your app on a remote server, so this is what you need.

1. Run `node server.js` locally continuously. To do this you can use `pm2` which is installed using `yarn` on `npm`. Make sure you install it globally:

   ```
   npm install pm2 -g
   ```

   then navigate to your root folder and run your app using

   ```
   pm2 start server.js
   ```

   Your app is now daemonized, monitored and kept alive forever.
2. Now we head to nginx. you will need to make edits to the config file by the name `default` in this location: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
   ```

   Now look for the closing tag of:

   ```
   server {


   } #this is its closing tag
   ```
3. Add a proxy before the closing tag to direct all traffic from port 80 to your app ...

   say for example my server.js app is running on port 3000 locally, i will add this code so that the file looks like this:

   ```
   server{

       #a bunch of code that was preexisting.......

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       }

   }
   ```

At least this would give some insights to what you are after.... hope it helps.

Comment: Althought i made it before your answer, but its correct, did the same.